# Python XML: write " instead of &quot

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am using Python's xml minidom and all works well except that in text sequences it writes out `&quot` escape characters instead of `"`. This of course makes sense if a quote appears in a tag, but it bugs me in the text. How do I change this?

Comment: Do you mean you want `&quot;` in text, and `"` in tags?

Comment: No, other way around:

`<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<article title="boy says &quot; bla&quot;">
A little boy woke up and said "bla"
</article>`
Or is this not possible?

Comment: XML parsers will not distinguish between the two. It will be "read" as `"` in the XML InfoSet. Why do you care which way the quotes are encoded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looking at the source (Python 3.2 if it matters), this is hardcoded in the _write_data() function.  you would need to modify the writexml() method of TextNode - either by subclassing it or simply editing it - so that it didn't call that method, but instead did something similar to escape only < and >.

if you created a subclass outside of the package (instead of copying and hacking the package to make your own custom xmlminidom) then it looks like, with a little care, you could make things work.  so you would create your own (subclass of) TextNode, modified as above and then, to add text to the DOM, you would add an instance of your new class (or replace existing text nodes with instances of that class).  you would need to set the ownerDocument attribute.  perhaps simplest would be to also subclass Document and fix the createTextNode() method.

but i don't see a simpler way of doing what you want.  it might be best to use a better dom implementation.

ps i have no idea whether this behaviour is required by the xml spec, or not.  update: a quick scan of http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax suggests that only < and & *must* be encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems like a lot of work for something that probably isn't worth it. I followed your advice and found a different xml Library, lxml works very well :)