# python minidom doesn't print out double quotes in the xml

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am using minidom and it works okay except for printing `&quot;` instead of printing ". I found out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030463/python-xml-write-instead-of-quot) which asks the solution for same problem but nobody has mentioned any good solution and besides the question is older than 2 years. Hence I wanted to see if anyone knows any new mechanism which addresses this problem. The workaround that I have currently for this problem is :

```
fw = open(fileFullPath, 'w')
dom.writexml(fw)
fw.close()
fw = open(fileFullPath, "r")
text = fw.read()
fw.close()
text = text.replace("&quot;","\"")
fw = open(fileFullPath, "w")
fw.write(text)
fw.close()
```

edit : I have this problem because my code is just a xml writer. I am not sure whether it will be always read using an xml reader or not. Hence the presence of " is so important.

Answer (score 0):

`"` is an xml literal - it's being replaced on purpose, to keep the xml valid. It should also escape things like `>`, `<`, `&`, etc. Don't worry, when you use minidom (or any other xml reader) and get the values, your double-quote will come back - that's the point of an xml escape....

Comment: thats the problem. I am just a writer of the xml and I am in no way sure that it will be read through an xml reader.

Comment: i'm not sure how else it could be read, but the post you linked to implies that the xml spec does not necessarily require it to be replaced, so i guess it doesn't _have_ to be. otherwise, you'd be trying to intentionally create invalid xml. the other post also implies that lxml does not do this particular substitution, maybe you could try that?

Comment: AFAIK, only & and < should be escaped in the text, and > should be escaped too in certain cases. Escaping  ' and " doesn't make sense unless they are in attribute values. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/.